# Debian Wheezy laptop has issues with suspension

Tags: laptop, debian-wheezy, suspend

I have Debian Wheezy installed on my Acer Aspire 5560G laptop. I have set it to suspend on lid close, which seems to be working fine. However, after a while, if I try to 'wake' the laptop up, I instead just get a black screen with nothing on it, which can only be fixed by forcefully shutting down and restarting the machine.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with the laptop or the OS (given that Debian never ceases surprising me...), so I would appreciate any and all help on this.